# Button lose listener after fragment replace

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment

I have the weirdest bug on Kotlin, and after two days of trying I finally asking for help.
The problem is simple : I have two fragment and one activity, the first fragment A is a form, with a validate button, when I click on validate, the fragment B replace the fragment A, and if I press back, the fragment A show up again with the form filled.

My problem is that after the fragment is shown again, I can click on the button but the listener is not call, so I can't go to the fragment B again. The strange thing is that the other listener are properly working, so I'm thinking it's because the previous fragment is catching the onClick, but idk what to do. Here is some code :

**ViewUtils :**

```
fun addFragment(activity: Activity, fragment: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, container: Int) {
    val fragmentManager = (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
    val pendingTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(container, fragment, fragment.javaClass.name)
    pendingTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
}

fun replaceFragment(manager: FragmentManager, fragment: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, container: Int) {
    if (fragment.isAdded) return
    val pendingTransaction = mangaer.beginTransaction()
    pendingTransaction.replace(container, fragment, fragment.javaClass.name)
    pendingTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
}

fun removeFragment(activity: Activity, fragment: Fragment) {
    val manager = (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
    val trans = manager.beginTransaction()
    trans.remove(fragment)
    trans.commit()
    manager.popBackStack()
}
```

**Activity :**

```
fun displayFragmentA() {
    ViewUtils.replaceFragment(supportFragmentManager, FragmentA,
            R.id.fragmentLayout)
}

fun FragmentB() {
    ViewUtils.replaceFragment(supportFragmentManager, FragmentB,
            R.id.fragmentLayout)
}
```

**Fragment A**

```
class AFragment : BaseFragment(), AContract.View {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(): AFragment {
            val fragment = AFragment()
            return fragment
        }
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var APresenter: AContract.Presenter<AContract.View>
    //end region

    //region lifecycle
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A_layout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        button_validate.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.goToNextStep()
        }
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }
```

The listener was set in the onViewCreated but I tried moving it to onResume (didn't change anything)

Fragment B code is not important I think, but I can add it if it helps.

Any help is welcome, I really don't know what's going on, the replace/add methods were there before I came to the project, they are not perfect but they are working elsewhere on the project.

I try using breakpoint, the button is not null but we never enter the listener.

Edit : I tried on 3 differents devices, I don't have the bug with a Sony Android 9, but with Huawei et One plus 6 Android 10, the problem persist ..

Comment: So are you saying when you go back from fragment B to grahemA your breakpoint in onResume is hit? But the actual code in the listener never executes?

Comment: An aside I would highly recommend looking at Jetpack Navigation https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation its the newer way of navigating and solves many other issues you will run into along the way with doing navigation yourself

Comment: Can you show us Fragment A code

Comment: are you shure that `onClickListener` isn't firing at all or maybe just `goToNextStep()` doesn't work when used/pressed again?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Exactly, the breakpoint in onResume hit but the actual code in the listener never executes, idk why. 
I know Jetpack navigation sound awesome but I'm working on a huge project and unfortunatly I can't change now

Comment: @snachmsm Yes I'm sure, the breakpoint isn't hit but I can try adding a log if needed

Comment: @RahulChaurasia I add some code from Fragment A but idk if it helps

Comment: @RomainHuber I wanted to check how you are initialising the view it is not clear from this code snippet. Like how the button is getting initialised

Comment: You mean that you want the xml ? Because in fragment himself, you can find the initialisation of the listener in onResume. This is the only thing I have to do to initiate the button

Comment: I tried on 3 differents devices, I don't have the bug with a Sony Android 9, but with Huawei et One plus 6 Android 10, the problem persist ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after asking to a lot of people, the only solution I found is not using kotlin.synthetic, and using findById instead :

```
view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_validate.setOnClickListener
```